Bounding the probability of a random variable when the expectation is also bounded?
Assume we have this given $\mathbb{E}[X] \leq \alpha$ where X is a non-negative random variable and $\alpha$ is a threshold value (e.g. 0.1). I want to bound the probability of X using this assumption. This is trivial using Markov's inequality for $P(X \geq \epsilon)$ when $\epsilon > 1$:
$$P(X \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{\epsilon} \leq \frac{\alpha}{\epsilon}$$
When $\epsilon \geq 1$ this leads to the bound on the probability getting tighter and thus upper bounds the probability of X. The issue is when we look at the probability when $0 < \epsilon < 1$. This leads to the problem that as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ then $\frac{\alpha}{\epsilon} \rightarrow \infty$. Is there a way to bound $P(X \geq \epsilon)$ when $0 < \epsilon < 1$?

Well, X could be $\alpha$ with probability 1...

Suppose $X=\alpha$ with probability 1. Then for $\epsilon \le \alpha$, we have $P(X\ge \epsilon)=1$, so there's no way to get a nontrivial upper bound without more assumptions.
